# ASP.NET non-persistent cookie (aka session cookie) not time out for some users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web project that uses non-persistent cookie (aka session cookie). The requirement is that a logged in session will time out either after 30 mins of inactivity or, users closes the web browser.

The project is in production, and some users reported that they don't need to login after days of usage. But they have to login at the beginning of using the project. The defect cannot be replicated on Testing Servers so far. Again, the defect **don't** happen for every user, and happens to some users **after** some usages.

Below is main code:

1) use `cookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue`;  //create non-persistent cookie.

2) Use `FormsAuthentication.Encrpt()` method to encrypt ticket

3) Use form element in web.config `timeout` attribute to validate timeout

The code above explains the main logic.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, setting `cookie.Expires` always create persistent cookie if the date is in future or deletes the cookie if the date is in the past.

The line

```
cookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue;
```

is somewhat confusing then. It looks like you are deleting the cookie so that when it gets to the client, it should be invalidated by the browser. The information you provide is not consistent then.

To have non-persistent cookies, never touch the `Expires` property. Instead, set the valid date inside the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`. The cookie will then hit the server but the ticket inside will make it invalid. Token validity and cookie expiry date are two unrelated dates and you should rely on the first one.

My guess is that for some users, the first page can possibly be read from the browser cache. Firefox caches aggresively and we have observed such behavior. One of possible ways to work this around is to turn of caching at the page level so that the browser is told to always ask the server for the newest version of the page and thus users have to relogin.

Comment: If I remember correctly, using DateTime.MinValue is the default way for session cookie in ASP.NET. The defect doesn't happen for everyone. Even that happens, it is after some usages.

Comment: Are you sure it is not caching issue?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. There is caching in Production. But why does Caching cause the issue? Do you mean caching for cookies or for form authentication ticket?

Comment: Tickets cannot be cached, cookies are cached. I don't know what caching system you have and what it caches but consider it as a possible culprit.